# tkinter progress bar won't update when called from an other app

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am developing a GUI with tkinter to manage images in a database (import file, load file, query, ...)

When a new directory and its sub-directories are scanned for new images to put in the database, a dedicated GUI is launched: 
It consists of a Text widget where the name of the directory currently analysed is printed, and a progress-bar showing the progress of the scan. 
When I call this GUI alone, the progressbar updates and progresses correctly as long as I use update() after each change in the progressbar. On the other hand, 
the Text widget is corretly updating even if I do no use update.

However, the progress bar does not update as it should when I call it from the main GUI, while the Text widget updates correctly.

I hope someone can help!

Below is the code for the progressbar GUI. I am using Python 3.6.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class ScanDirectoryForJPG(Tk):
    """
    Inherited from the Tk class
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, Path=None):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.PathDicom = Path
        if self.Path == None:
            self.Path = askdirectory(title='Select a directory to scan')

        self.title('Scan {} for JPG files'.format(self.Path))
        self.status_string = 'Scanning the content of {} folder\n'.format(self.Path)
        self.initialize_gui()
        self.scan_directory()

    def initialize_gui(self):

        # Style
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use('vista')

        # Main window
        self.grid()
        self.grid_columnconfigure([0], weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure([0], weight=1)

        # Status
        self.status_label = Text(self)
        self.status_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
        self.status_label.insert(END, 'Looking for JPG files in {}\n'.format(self.Path))

        # Progress Bar
        self.p = DoubleVar()
        self.progress_bar = Progressbar(self, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', variable=self.p, maximum=100)
        self.p.set(0)
        self.progress_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=1, sticky='EW')

    def scan_directory(self):
        """

        """
        number_of_files = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(self.Path)])
        count = 0

        for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(self.Path):
            self.status_label.insert(END, '\t-exploring: {}\n'.format(dirName))
            self.update()

            for filename in fileList:
                count += 1
                value = count / number_of_files * self.progress_bar['maximum']
                if value >= (self.progress_bar['value'] + 1):
                    # update the progress bar only when its value is increased by at least 1 (avoid too much updates of the progressbar)
                    self.p.set(self.progress_bar['value'] + 1)
                    self.update()

                file = os.path.join(dirName, filename)

                # if the file is a JPG, load it into the database
                # ...
                # ...
                # ..

        self.status_label.insert(END, 'FINISH\n')
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = ScanDirectoryForJPG(None, Path='D:\Data\Test')
    app.mainloop()
    print('App closed')
```

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to: "Why doesn't the progress bar update when it's called from the main GUI?" What exactly do you mean when you say "call" it? I suspect you mean "call the class" which implies that `Tk.__init__()` gets called as a result. That could be the problem if it occurs from after another part of the program has also already called it because you can't have two `Tk` instances running at the same time—they don't play well together. There _are_ ways of creating more than one top-level window though, just not the way you [may] be doing it.

Comment: Yes you are right, I mean calling the class. I've seen on some forum people using threads and queue, but it is far too complicated for my level. So it seems that I am stuck with my problems? But then why does the Text widget updates correctly?

Comment: The usual way to create a second window is by creating an instance of (calling) [`tkinter.TopLevel`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html). Doing so would require **not** deriving the `ScanDirectoryForJPG` class from the `Tk` class. Which may actually be fairly easy to do. If you edit your post and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem, someone can probably show you how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to call `update()` in tkinter you are doing it wrong.

In this case you have a loop that walks the directory tree. For the whole time your code is within that loop you are not processing events promptly so you have to call `update()` all the time.

Instead, capture the output of the `os.walk` or simply collect the toplevel directory contents and then use `after` to process a single item at a time, passing the iterator or list along so once you process a single item, you call after again to process the next one. This way the mainloop will handle UI events promptly with your directory tree processing being queued as events along with everything else. You should fine the application more responsive once you rework it in this manner.

### Example

To demonstrate this, `os.walk` returns a generator so we can use after events to schedule each directory as each call of `next(generator)` yields the next directory with its files.

To monitor the progress we need some way to count the number of directories or files to be visited and if this demo is used for a whole filesystem that is where the app will appear to freeze. This could be broken into event-based code too to prevent this effect.

I used `after(10, ...)` to have it show the effect but for maximum speed, use `after_idle` instead.

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        #tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        parent.wm_withdraw()
        parent.wm_title(title)
        self.create_ui()
        self.grid(sticky = "news")
        parent.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_destroy)
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.wm_deiconify()

    def create_ui(self):
        textframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.text = text = tk.Text(textframe)
        vs = ttk.Scrollbar(textframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=text.yview)
        text.configure(yscrollcommand=vs.set)
        text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        vs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

        textframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        textframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        textframe.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.progressvar = tk.IntVar()
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, variable=self.progressvar)
        test_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Walk", command=self.on_walk)
        exit_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.on_destroy)
        self.progress.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        test_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.SE)
        exit_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.SE)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def on_destroy(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def on_walk(self):
        root = askdirectory()
        self.walk(root)

    def walk(self, root=None):
        if root:
            # this is potentially costly, but how to find the number of files to be examined?
            count = sum([len(files) for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(root)])
            self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
            self.progress.configure(maximum=count)
            self.progressvar.set(0)
            walker = os.walk(root)
            self.after(100, self.do_one, walker)

    def do_one(self, walker):
        try:
            root,dirs,files = next(walker)
            for file in files:
                self.text.insert(tk.END, os.path.join(root, file), "PATH", "\n", "")
                self.text.see(tk.END)
                self.progressvar.set(self.progressvar.get() + 1)
            self.after(10, self.do_one, walker)
        except StopIteration:
            pass


def main(args):
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root, "Walk directory tree")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not familiar with <after>. Can you show an example of how to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I could understand and adapt what you sent in my application! Best regards

Comment: Going back to your proposed solution, I tried it without after() or after_idle() and I could check that the progressbar does not update properly. But I do not understand 100% the reason why. Thanks