# How to call a function in tkinter after an other function has finished to execute?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi,

I know that event driven programming is very different than "traditional programming" where the instructions are executed sequentially by the program. However, I am new to it, and I do not understand 100% how does event driven programming works, and I think this is the reason of my problem here.

I built an example from the answer to this post:[tkinter progress bar won't update when called from an other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754385/tkinter-progress-bar-wont-update-when-called-from-an-other-app)

In this example, I would like that my program do an action after it has finished to scan the given path. Naively, I tried adding the call to `action` routine after the call to `walk`:

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        #tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        parent.wm_withdraw()
        parent.wm_title(title)
        self.create_ui()
        self.grid(sticky = "news")
        parent.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_destroy)
        parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.wm_deiconify()

    def create_ui(self):
        textframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.text = text = tk.Text(textframe)
        vs = ttk.Scrollbar(textframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=text.yview)
        text.configure(yscrollcommand=vs.set)
        text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        vs.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

        textframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        textframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        textframe.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.progressvar = tk.IntVar()
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, variable=self.progressvar)
        test_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Walk", command=self.on_walk)
        exit_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.on_destroy)
        self.progress.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        test_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.SE)
        exit_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.SE)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def on_destroy(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def on_walk(self):
        root = askdirectory()
        self.walk(root)
        self.action()

    def walk(self, root=None):
        if root:
            # this is potentially costly, but how to find the number of files to be examined?
            count = sum([len(files) for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(root)])
            self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
            self.progress.configure(maximum=count)
            self.progressvar.set(0)
            walker = os.walk(root)
            self.after(100, self.do_one, walker)

    def do_one(self, walker):
        try:
            root,dirs,files = next(walker)
            for file in files:
                self.text.insert(tk.END, os.path.join(root, file), "PATH", "\n", "")
                self.text.see(tk.END)
                self.progressvar.set(self.progressvar.get() + 1)
            self.after(10, self.do_one, walker)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

    def action(self):
        print('DO SOMETHING HERE, AFTER WALK HAS FINISHED\n')
```

By doing so, the `action` function is called before the end of the call to walk.

I figured a workaround by calling `action` after the exception in the `do_one` function:

```
def do_one(self, walker):
    try:
        root,dirs,files = next(walker)
        for file in files:
            self.text.insert(tk.END, os.path.join(root, file), "PATH", "\n", "")
            self.text.see(tk.END)
            self.progressvar.set(self.progressvar.get() + 1)
        self.after(10, self.do_one, walker)
    except StopIteration:
        self.action()
```

I guess that there is a better way to do it. Is there a way to create an event that tells to the program that the tasks performed by `walk` is finished?

Thanks

Comment: In what way do you expect another way to be better? You could compare `self.progressvar.get()` to `self.progress['maximum']` every time `do_one` is executed, but using the exception seems way more readable and intuitive to me and doesn't cause an extra action each step of the 'loop'.

Comment: I think this needs to be moved to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This question is not about how to fix code to work but rather how (if needed/possible) to improve functioning code.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your suggestion. I do not know how to do it though. However, I am not sure this should go to code review because the example is here to illustrate a more general question about event-driven programming with tkinter.